# Difference between Entity Framework DropForeignKey method between .Net Framework and .Net Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

The signature for the `DropForeignKey` method on an Entity Framework migration is as follows:

`protected internal void DropForeignKey(string dependentTable, string dependentColumn, string principalTable, object anonymousArguments = null)`

While the signature for the `DropForeignKey` method on an Entity Framework Core migration is as follows:

`public virtual OperationBuilder<DropForeignKeyOperation> DropForeignKey(string name, string table, string? schema = null)`

How does one translate to the other?

Comment: What is the problem  in understanding EF Core version? Get constraint name from database and drop it. Probably EF6 makes constraint name generation based on additional parameters.

Comment: Thats ultimately what I had to do. At the time of writing this question I didn't have the DB and assumed that the previous code was enough to write the upgraded code. I did not think I would need additional info. @SvyatoslavDanyliv